# how to overload = operator with js es5 Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

I what to overload the `=` operator for JS objects using `Object.defineProperty`.

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
var obj = { };
Object.defineProperty(obj,'var', {
  get: function() { log('get'); return obj._var; },
  set: function(v) { log('set'); obj._var = v; }
});
```

That's the standard es5 syntax for defining a simple property.
Now `obj.var` is a property with overloaded `=` operator.
But what i actually what to do is to overload `=` operator for the `obj` itself.

```
obj.var = 'a'; // prints: get
var v = obj.var;
v = 'b';  // prints: nothing!
// of course that's right, because v is an string now.
```

**How to overload the `=` operator for the object itself ?**

```
//i what something like this 
v = 'b'; // should print: set
```

*Is it possible (in es5) ?*

Comment: *Is it possible (in es5) ?* - No.

Comment: is it possible in es6 ?

Comment: Nope. Assignment operator binds the object on the right hand side to the left hand side identifier. So, its not possible.

Comment: OK, thanks. if you post an answer then i'll accept it.

Comment: why would you ever want to do this in the first place? What problem would it solve?

Comment: You can copy the property descriptor onto another object, but this may give unexpected results depending on how things are referenced (e.g. you reference `obj._var`, but a similar implementation could use `this._var` or a closure)

Comment: @PaulS. can you give an example. thanks.

Comment: @charlietfl **what problem would it solve ?**. I don't accept the premise of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You are in fact not overloading the `=` operator, you are overloading the `.` operator (or property accessors in general). Your getter / setter will be called whenever the *property* of your object is used. `v` is no more a property, it's just a variable that holds a value.

---

That said, while you cannot do this for arbitrary variables, the [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) does allow you to write code that looks like variable assignment and does what you expected:

```
with({
  get v() { console.log("get"); return 5; },
  set v(x) { console.log("set", x); }
}) {
  v = 5; // set 5
  console.log(v); // get, 5
}
```

Notice that this is really really scary and you really really should not do this. It's banned from strict mode for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

> You can copy the property descriptor onto another object, but this may give unexpected results depending on how things are referenced (e.g. you reference `obj._var`, but a similar implementation could use `this._var` or a closure) –  Paul S.

> @PaulS. can you give an example. thanks. –  amin

Say you have your definition set up

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
var obj = { };
Object.defineProperty(obj,'var', {
  get: function() { log('get'); return obj._var; },
  set: function(v) { log('set'); obj._var = v; }
});
```

Now copy the descriptor onto another *Object*,

```
var o2 = {}; // another object
Object.defineProperty(
    o2, 'copied_var',
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, 'var')
);
```

Then you can use these getters and setters through this **different object**

```
o2.copied_var = 1; // logs set
o2.copied_var;    // 1, logs get
```

But notice because of the reference in the functions is to `obj._var` we have

```
o2._var; // undefined
obj._var; // 1
obj.var; // 1 (same lookup), logs get
```